# WPF Application Automation Testing Framework support embedded Web pages

Tags: wpf, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, teststack

I am currently looking for automation open source framework & tool either in C#, Java or any language to automate WPF application.

I have already explore TestStack White for WPF automation and its working perfect for me. BUT

My WPF application has 60% to 70% are embedded web pages (HTML) Dynamics CRM forms are loading.

TestStack White doesn't support embedded web pages.

Please guide me any open source framework or tool which can help me to automate my UI & integration testing.

Comment: It depends which web browser engine is used inside WPF app. It should explicitly enable accessibility support for this engine. Then web UI controls will be visible in `Inspect.exe`.

Comment: I can't recall exactly how we did it (it was a while ago, and I don't have the source code since I no longer work there), but at a previous company we had the same scenario with WPF, White, and embedded web pages.  We were able to do a hand-off to selenium from White to automate the embedded web pages.  If you search for that perhaps you can find some more info.